# PG (Node-Postgres) Pool Hangs on Connect ... But Only Inside Gatsby?

Tags: node.js, gatsby, node-postgres, postgraphile

**NOTE:** This is mainly a question about the `pg` or Node-PostgreSQL module.  It has details from Gatsby and Postgraphile, but I don't need expertise in all three, just `pg`.

I have a database that works great with a PostGraphile-using Express server.  I can also acces it via `node` at the command line ...

```
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const pool = new Pool({ connectionString: myDbUrl });
pool.connect().then(() => console.log('connected'));
// logs 'connected' immediately
```

The exact same database also ***previously*** worked great with Gatsby/PostGraphile via the `gatsby-source-pg` plug-in ... but recently I changed dev machines, and when I try to build or run a dev server, Gatsby hangs on the "source and transform nodes" step.  When I debug it, it's hanging on a call to `pool.connect()`.

So I literally have two codebases both using PostGraphile, both with the same config, and one works and the other doesn't.  Even stranger, if I edit the source code of the Gatsby plug-in in `node_modules`, to make it use *the exact same code* (which I can run at the command line successfully) ... it still hangs.

The only thing I can think of is that some other Gatsby plug-in is using up all the connections and not releasing them, but as far as I can tell (eg. by grep-ing through `node_modules`) no other plug-in even uses `pg`.

So really I have two questions:

A) Can anyone help me understand why `connect` would hang?  Bonus points if you can help me understand why it would do so with a known-good config and *only* inside Gatsby (after some environmental factor changed)?

B) Can anyone help me fix it? If it might be some sort of "previous code forgot to release connections" issue, is there any way I can test for that?  If I could just log `new Pool().areYouBroken()` somehow that would be amazingly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annoying answer: because of a bug (thank you @charmander).  For further details see: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2300

P.S. I never did find any sort of `new Pool().areYouBroken()` function.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
npm install pg@latest
```

This is what got my pool/connection to start working as expected.